# Как в поле input разрешить ввод только двух цифр?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно внести дополнения в скрипт, чтобы во втором поле input с `id="din"` разрешить ввод только двух цифр, а после них через пробел добавлялось три ноля (как в первом поле добавляется +7) ? Спасибо!

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
    elem.focus();
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    else if (elem.createTextRange) {
        var range = elem.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd("character", pos);
        range.moveStart("character", pos);
        range.select()
    }
}

function mask(event) {
    var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
    this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
        return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? "" : a
    });
    if (event.type == "blur") {
        if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = ""
    } else setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this)
};
    var input = document.querySelector("#tel");
    input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="tel" class="f_input" />
<input type="text" name="" id="din" class="f_input" />
```

Comment: Мне кажется, Вам подойдет это: https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Comment: Мне кажется вам надо немного поразбираться с JavaScript самостоятельно, почитать документацию, книги, поделать задачки. У вас очень много подобных вопросов. Это не очень рационально по каждому такому вопросу спрашивать сообщество, если по-сути вы сами всё это сможете легко сделать изучив JavaScript в хорошей мере. А так трата и вашего времени и тех кто отвечает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
    elem.focus();
    if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
    else if (elem.createTextRange) {
      var range = elem.createTextRange();
      range.collapse(true);
      range.moveEnd("character", pos);
      range.moveStart("character", pos);
      range.select()
    }
  }

  function mask(event) {
    var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
      i = 0,
      def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
      val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
    if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
    this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
      return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? "" : a
    });
    if (event.type == "blur") {
      if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = ""
    } else setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this)
  };

  function maskTi(event) {
    var nval = "";
    var val = this.value.toString().replace(/\s000/, '').replace(/[\D]/g, '');

    if (val.length != 0) {
      val = nval = val.replace(/^([1-9][0-9])\d*$/, '$1');
      if (val[0] != 0) this.value = val + " 000";
      else this.value = "";
    } else {
      this.value = "";
    }
    setCursorPosition(nval.length, this);
  }


  var input1 = document.querySelector("#tel");
  input1.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
  input1.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
  input1.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);

  var input2 = document.querySelector("#din");
  input2.addEventListener("input", maskTi, false);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="tel" class="f_input" />
<input type="text" name="" id="din" class="f_input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


function setCursorPosition(pos, elem) {
elem.focus();
if (elem.setSelectionRange) elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
else if (elem.createTextRange) {
    var range = elem.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd("character", pos);
    range.moveStart("character", pos);
    range.select()
}
}

function mask(event) {
var matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
    i = 0,
    def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
    val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
if (def.length >= val.length) val = def;
this.value = matrix.replace(/./g, function(a) {
    return /[_\d]/.test(a) && i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) : i >= val.length ? "" : a
});
if (event.type == "blur") {
    if (this.value.length == 2) this.value = ""
} else setCursorPosition(this.value.length, this)
};
var input = document.querySelector("#tel");
input.addEventListener("input", mask, false);
input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false);
input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false);

var din = document.getElementById("din");
din.addEventListener("keypress", controlNumber);
din.addEventListener("keydown", controlNumber);

function controlNumber(event){
    din.addEventListener("input", addNumber);
    var code = event.keyCode;
    console.log(code)
    if (code == 8 || code == 46 ){
        din.removeEventListener("input", addNumber);
        return;
    } else if (code > 34 && code < 41){
        console.log("nen")
        return;
    } else if (code < 48 || code  > 57)
         event.preventDefault();
 }

function addNumber(){
    if(din.value.length == 2){
        din.value += " 000";
    }
}
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="tel" class="f_input" />
<input type="text" name="" maxlength="2" id="din" class="f_input" />;
```

Comment: " разрешить ввод только двух цифр, а после них через пробел добавлялось три ноля "

Comment: забыл изменить тип инпута на number. Изменил - а такой тип, оказывается - не поддерживает атрибут `maxlength`)). Надо переделывать код)

Comment: та надо переделывать. Удалю ответ

Comment: заработало. 53 минуты делал)

Comment: `разрешить ввод только двух цифр, а после них через пробел добавлялось три ноля` - это из вопроса. Две цифры вводятся  - после них добавляются нули.  Боковая клавиатура - да, ее у меня нет и этого я не учел. Поэтому удобнее скрипт через regExp написать. Буду знать.